# convert multiple strings to one and not use empty once?

Tags: java, android

Trying to do a list that I can send by SMS. but the problem is that I looks like crap when it includes empty strings. Is there any way to exclude the empty strings or format the new string so it becomes more readable? or maybe format the message string so it removes extra unwanted spaces or commas?

```
   message = s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7 + s8 + s9 + s10;
   Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
   sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
   startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Tried to put commas between them and spaces but it doesn't look good with `"One,Two,,Four,,,,Nine,Ten"` for example..
Searched a lot for a solution but can't find any. Not sure what to search for. 
Any way to fix this?

Comment: You can just do trim

Comment: Well, what do you *want* the result to be. Without a clear goal, how can you expect to get there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting it to a place where you have it seperated by comma's you can do something like this

```
message = message.replaceAll("[,]+", " ");
```

Which will get all instances of 1 or more comma's and replace them with a space so:
   `","` will become `" "` and `"testing,,,,,test1,,,test2,,test3 test4"` will become `"testing test1 test2 test3 test4"`

regex is great for the find and replace type operations. you can build your own with this helpful tool http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Nice.. :)  will check out that page.. thanks for your reply. :) works now with a few adjustments. :)